# How to preserve processing instructions whilst producing XSL-FO in eXist-db?

Tags: xslt, exist-db, processing-instruction

Is there a way to make eXist to return processing instruction as it is? It seems it somehow ignores it in the output.

Processing instructions are very useful if I use XEP as my rendering engine, hence it would be great to be able to preserve them before the root of the XSL-FO document or immediately after its start.

If I have in the template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
        <?xep-pdf-page-layout two-columns-right?>
```

It simply returns:

```
<fo:root xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
```

I’ve tried to touch preserving of processing instructions with:
`declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/xml process-xsl-pi=yes";` in the prolog of my query but to no avail.

**UPDATE I**

The steps of my scenario are:

1. loading the document from the DB
2. passing it to the `transform:transform()` function
3. whilst calling the `transform:transform()` function, I pass to it one basic stylesheet, which includes other stylesheets
4. I need to add the processing instruction to a stylesheet for `pages-masters`, which covers the root of the FO document later used by the rendering engine. This stylesheet is included (`<xsl:include/>`) into the basic one (gathering all the stylesheets) and passed to the function.

Comment: Can you state the steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I have just updated the question!

Comment: @joewiz this sounds like a bug to me, since the prolog declaration doesn't seem to affect the query results as expected. Honja, have you tried using [computed constructor syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-computed-pis) in your xquery to see if the PI is preserved there?

Comment: @duncdrum From the answer marked as correct below, it appears to me that the issue was at the XSLT level (i.e., within the scope of the transform:transform function), not at the level of the XQuery calling the XSLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With XSLT, to output a processing instruction use https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#creating-processing-instructions, that is `<xsl:processing-instruction name="xep-pdf-page-layout">two-columns-right</xsl:processing-instruction>` to have the pi `<?xep-pdf-page-layout two-columns-right?>` in the transformation result.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the right version in my case is `<xsl:processing-instruction name="xep-pdf-page-layout">two-columns-right</xsl:processing-instruction>`. If you can, please, update the answer and I will mark it as solving my issue.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl, sorry, I had not  noticed the space and just thought it were a pi without data. Now corrected.